# Java: How do I unit test a method that creates and manipulates a file within the scope of the method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I'm using JUnit and JMockit to create a unit test method that tests the creation and manipulation of a CSV file. How do I intercept the file that is being created to ensure that is created correctly?

```
@Test
public void testPersistResultsAsCSV() throws IOException {
    final Long id = new Long(1234l);

    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    row.setValue(317l);
    row.setId(1234l);

    final List<TableRow> rows = new ArrayList<TableRow>();
    rows.add(row);

    final List<TableRow> empty = new ArrayList<TableRow>();

    new Expectations() {
        {
            tableService.findTableRowsById(id, (TableQueryOptions)any);
            result = rows;

            tableService.findTableRowsById(id, (TableQueryOptions)any);
            result = empty;

            fileDataService.saveResultsFile((ResultsFile) any);

        }
    };

    resultsToCsvService.persistResultsAsCSV(id);

}
```

Comment: Can you post a code that you try to test, rather than a unit test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am the creator of JMockit, but I will happily say "don't use JMockit" for this.

You *can* mock the Java IO classes, but that is almost never a good idea; instead, use a real file on the local filesystem. Your test will be simpler, less fragile, and fast enough (unless you do something bad like reading/writing big files, a large number of them, or accessing a slow remote directory - but none of these should occur in a well-written test).

When people mock the IO API (ie, `File`, `FileWriter`, etc.) they inevitably end up with a test that is tightly coupled to the implementation of the code under test, and therefore complicated and fragile. In practice, it's just better to let the test touch the filesystem; if that makes it an "integration test", so be it.

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor your method under test so that you're supplying it with an output stream or writer instead of having it open the file itself. This is a good idea generally, even outside the context of unit testing, since it makes the code more reusable; for example, you might want to write the output to a socket or compressed stream.

Answer (score 0):

Should probably use a Rule (dumbest name ever, really has nothing to do with rules per se).

[Rules for Files in Unit Tests](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/junit-tip-use-rules-to-manage-temporary-files-and-folders/)

Comment: I would give you an upvote if you concretely explained how to use the Rule for this context.

Comment: You are trying to verify that given proper starting data the file ends up getting created, no? The applicability of a rule here is that you have a little sandbox into which whatever file operations your code does it will go, then you can easily check to see if it was there. Or, if you want it to not create the file given incorrect information, assert that it's not there. The main thing it's doing is providing a fixture so that you don't have to: a. refer to files in a way that might be different on different machines, and b. clean up after yourself.

Comment: So the Rule provide simply a temp folder to work with (inside) it. As the original question suggested, @reece-long probably wanted something more fancy than that (so do I), as he is using mocking. 
But maybe there is not better way of testing IO side efects than actually test for ordinary java operations on files (exists, size...).

Comment: Yeah I can see what he is asking for and using mocking is a great idea. At some point though, I do want to have tests that show me that the real thing actually happened. They are for sure not mutually exclusive.